ADLS Gen2 to Snowflake reading partial files
I am loading files present in ADLS Gen2 into Snowflake.
Files are being written every 10 mins in ADLS under a timestamp folder.
Snowflake is reading every 10 min from the unprocessed folders.
I have observed that I am able to list and load files into snowflake which are currently being written by Azure process.
I was under the assumption, Snowflake will only be able to list files which are complete and Azure would perform an atomic operation on creating the file.
I haven't faced this issue with GCS.
Is this a property of ADLS Gen2? Or this is based on some configuration?

Is there any wait time in the snowflake before processing?, so that you can set a max wait time which helps to process completely loaded files.

@RakeshGovindula I can delay the snowflake run about don't think that would be the most logical solution. Ideally I would assume there to be some configuration in ADLS Gen2 which only allows Snowflake to list completed files

I think Snowflake assumes (likely correctly) that a file loaded to a blob storage won't be registered until the file is done being created.  I don't know ADLS Gen2, but it seems like it shouldn't be a visible file until the object in blob is done being created.

Perhaps this snippet from docs will help? For Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage accounts, Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated events are triggered when clients use the CreateFile and FlushWithClose operations. If the SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) is used, Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated events are triggered with SftpCreate and SftpCommit operations. The CreateFile or SftpCreate API alone does not indicate a commit of a file in the storage account. If the FlushWithClose or SftpCommit message is not sent, Snowflake does not refresh the directory table.
